# How to bind OData directly to XMLView

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I have an UI5 app in which I have a table defined in my XMLView. I'm making a call to the backend using OData to retrieve the data. I'm doing it the following way.

```
 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("url to data", true);
            var inputModel = new JSONModel();

            oModel.read("/Products",
                null,
                null,
                false,
                function _OnSuccess(oData, response) {
                    var data = oData.results;
                    inputModel.setData(data);
                },
                function _OnError(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            //set model(s) to current xml view
            this.getView().setModel(inputModel, "inputModel");
```

How can I do this without having to create the JSON model, I mean bind the oData directly to the XMLView.

I have seen it being done but only with JSView, e.g:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("http://admin-   think:88/sap/...",{useBatch : true});
  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"model1");

// Create instance of table 
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
visibleRowCount : 6,
    selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single, 
    navigationMode: sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.scrollbar, 
    selectionBehavior: sap.ui.table.SelectionBehavior.RowOnly
});

// First column "Application"
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
       label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
             text : "APPLICATION",
             textAlign : "Center",

       }),
       template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
            textAlign:"Center"}).bindProperty("text","model1>Applno"),              
}));

// Bind model to table control    
 oTable.bindRows("model1>/");
```

This way it seems like a lot of work. How can I do something like this but using an XML view?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I've read some(sapui5 api and other sources) but I'm not really getting it to be honest. Mind pointing me to what documentation you are referring to?

Comment: I understand why someone would downvote such questions but IMHO, the documentation of UI5 is a jungle with no proper search functionality, which makes it hard for beginners.
@polaris: I'd suggest to take some days and go through Walkthrough steps in the dev guide: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html

Comment: The structure of the documentation should be improved, no question. But it even beginners shall be able to find the Tutorials section and the part which handles binding... just my two cents...

Answer (score 1):

XML Code :

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.m.sample.Table.Table"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Table id="idProductsTable"
        inset="false"
        items="{Data>/Table}">
        <columns>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Name" />
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <Text text="id" />
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Text
                        text="{Data>name}" />
                    <Text
                        text="{Data>id}" />
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</mvc:View>
```

JS Code :

```
onAfterRendering : function(){
   var oView = this.getView();
   var oTableJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   var fnSuccess = function(oEvent,oResponse){
      var Data = {
          Table : oData.results,
      };
      oTableJSON.setData(Data);   
      oView.byId("idProductsTable").setModel(oTableJSON,"Data");
   };
   oModel("/ProductionSet",null,null,true,fnSuccess,fnFail);
}
```